# How do I add a red title to a link in a comment?

Tags: support

Presently I can only paste a URL into a comment and the word processor chooses what title to say in red.

How do I add my own title to the link ?

Comment: Test (as below) [This Question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11246/how-do-i-add-a-red-title-to-a-link-in-a-comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This confused me too, because the style of link used by the graphical user interface tool in questions and answers creates a footnote style link that does not work in the comments. Hypertext Markup Language does not work either, so you need to use *inline* markdown links, which I suppose makes sense given the relatively short and transient nature of comments.

Inline links are written with square brackets enclosing the text, and parenthesis enclosing the U.R.L., like this:

`[Hey! Visit Stack Exchange!](https://stackexchange.com)`

The result of typing that into a comment should be like this:

[Hey! Visit Stack Exchange!](https://stackexchange.com)

You can read more about [Markdown formatting options in the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and details about what hypertext markup language can be used in Stack Exchange posts [at Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/371286).

Comment: And `[Hey! Visit Stack Exchange!](https://stackexchange.com "Visit SE")` will add a tooltip. It might work in comments: let's see... [Hey! Visit Stack Exchange!](https://stackexchange.com "Visit SE")